# Java xml preview using css

Tags: java, css, xml, swing

Am developing one simple XML `WYSIWYG editor` in java swing, here i have used **JTabbedPane**,  one tab for XML source and another tab for XML preview. In this i want to display the XML preview without using the xslt using css, I tried **HTMLEditorKit** but its not suitable for me, Is there any alternate way to preview the XML file, any one suggest me the correct way?

Source
[image]

My Excepted output in Jeditorpane
[image]

Comment: May be this one https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: *"XML WYSIWYG"*  It is XSLT that makes XML formatted ('See'able).  The term 'XML WYSIWYG' makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Did u see oxygen editor, they use css only for xml preview.thats why i post my question is there any option available in java swing?